# Implications of changing MemCached maximum block size

Tags: caching, memcached, distributed-caching

What (if any) are the downsides of running MemCached with say 100MB maximum cache block sizes?

Would it run any significantly different to using 10MB or 1MB pages? Reversely, why would you run MemCached with smaller pages such as 100k?

If MemCached was set to use 100MB maximum size, would it actually allocate 100MB for every memory unit regardless of how big it actually was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-memcached-using-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

memcached is an object cache that is most beneficial for accessing objects with low latency.

If your items are 100MB, you'd have to have a ridiculously fast network for latency to be an issue.  At that point, you should just use varnish or similar and deal with the parsing overhead of an HTTP request since the bulk of the load time is going to be in transfer.

Comment: I'm dealing entirely with short length fiber connections between all of my endpoints